# C#: ensure a decimal has 2 floating point places

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a webService with a method that takes a parameter of type decimal. This parameter must have 2 floating point places.
How can I ensure that?

```
public void callMyWS(decimal d1) {
   ...
   decimal d2 = Ensure2FloatingPointPlaces(d1);

   proxy.MyWSmethod(d2);
}
```

.

```
MyWSmethod(decimal myDD) { ... }
```

MyWSmethod has a validation for the two places. So:
If "d1" is 1.00   => everything is okay.
If "d1" is 1    => validation fails.

The main problem is if d1 is integer-like.

I read something about the "m"-suffix. But all examples are with constant numbers which is not very helpful... As you can also see it isn't the goal to convert to a string.

Let's have a look at the xsd:

```
<xs:element name="MyWSmethod" type="tns:MyWSmethodType"/>
...
<xs:complexType name="MyWSmethodType">
    <xs:sequence>     
    ...
       <xs:element name="myDecimal" type="myDecimalType"/>
    ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
...
<xs:simpleType name="myDecimalType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:pattern value="[\-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

So when you build the webservice client from the xsd, you will have the restriction of the 2 floating point places.

Comment: What do you mean by "This parameter must have 2 floating point places"? What exactly ensuring this helps you with?

Comment: A decimal number has a specified set of numbers you can't force it to be shorter or longer... the only thing you can do is to display a certain number of numbers after the floating point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Round to truncate to two decimal places, but you will have to update your validation anyway.

Make sure you validation passes on these values:

- 1
- 1.11
- 1.1
- .1
- .11

Comment: First and main point: I don't have access to the validation. And if: the xsd - which give the base for it - is defined. I *cannot* change it.  I have got the most problems with values that have no floating point part (eg. 1 ).